# Problemas al mostrar un archivo PDF en el navegador

Tags: php, pdf

Estoy mostrando un archivo PDF que desarrollé con la librería [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) en PHP y al hacerle clic en el botón, se abre una pestaña nueva, pero la pestaña se queda en blanco, solamente se observa una foto que tengo de fondo en el PDF y la típica imagen de cargando *(como un circulo dando vueltas)* en medio de la pagina y no se muestra nada más, pero luego de recargar la página se carga bien y muestra la información.

Por que podría estar pasando esto?

**EDIT**

El botón para llamar a crear el PDF

```
<td>
    <?php
        // PDF
        if($borrador == 1){ //SI ES BORRADOR
    ?>
    <a href="index.php?p=pdf_borrador&id=<?php echo $row['ID_SOL']; // echo $row['id_spom']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-title="View" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
    <?php
        }else if ($borrador == 0){ //SI ES SOLICITUD
    ?>
    <a href="index.php?p=pdf_solicitud&id=<?php echo  $row['ID_SOL']; // echo $row['id_spom']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-title="View" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</td>
```

Cabeceras del PDF (primeras líneas)

```
<?php
 define('FPDF_FONTPATH','_fpdf/font/');
 require('_fpdf/fpdf.php');
 $pdf=new FPDF('P','mm',array(216,330));
 $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,10);
 $pdf->AddPage();
 $pdf->SetFillColor(194,194,194);
 $pdf->SetLineWidth(0.1);

 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',7);
 $pdf->Text(10,4,'titulo1');

 $pdf->Text(166,4,'titulo2');

 ob_end_clean();
 $pdf->Output('m_pdf_xxxx.php','i');
?>
```

Espero les aclare un poco mas el tema. Obviamente es un PDF mucho mas extenso pero no puedo colocarlo todo aquí, probé esto en mi localhost y pasa lo mismo.

Agradecido!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta mal tu escritura del PDF. Debe ser asi:

```
$pdfRecibo = $pdf->Output("",'S');
```

La opcion S te devuelve el binario a una variable, por lo que no necesitas la ruta, por eso la mande vacia. Luego al final de tu php haz esto:

```
echo $pdfRecibo;
```

Por ultimo en javascript con jquery:

```
function consultarCFDI(noCFDI,campo,ejercicio_registro){
    $.ajax({
       url : "archivo.php",
       type : 'POST',
       dataType : 'text',
       data :  { noCFDI: noCFDI,campo:campo,EJERCICIO_REGISTRO:ejercicio_registro },
       success : function(binario) {
           //alert(binario);
           var nombreLogico = campo;
           var parametros = "dependent=yes,locationbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,resizable,screenX=50,screenY=50,width=850,height=1050";
           var htmlText = "<embed width=100% height=100% type='application/pdf' src='data:application/pdf,"+escape(binario)+"'></embed>"; 
           var detailWindow = window.open ("", nombreLogico, parametros);
           detailWindow.document.write(htmlText);
           detailWindow.document.close();
       },
       error : function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                       alert("error\njqXHR="+jqXHR+"\nstatus="+status+"\nerror="+error);
       },
       complete : function(jqXHR, status) {

       }
    });
}
```

y revisa la codificacion de caracteres al pasar de php a javascript, eso te puede afectar y tal vez tengas que usar utf8_encode o utf8_decode