# No grabar PDF (FPDF) en el servidor

Tags: php, fpdf

En un entorno de Intranet estoy generando un PDF con PHP, visualizándolo con:

```
$pdf->Output($file,'F');
```

Funciona perfecto, pero NO quiero grabarlo en el servidor, sólo que se abra en el navegador.

He probado con todas las opciones y la única que me abre el PDF en el navegador es `F`.

Les agradeceré si me pueden orientar. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Según la documentacion de fpdf estas enviando los parametros al revés,  en lugar de así **$pdf->Output($file,'F');**, debería ser asi **$pdf->Output('F', $name);**   http://www.fpdf.org/es/doc/output.htm

Comment: @Xerif, el comentario va más como respuesta :D

Comment: @fredyfx Si y no, me parece un error tipográfico y quizas no tenga mucho sentido la pregunta. y una respuesta tan simple... creo que tampoco.

Answer (score 1):

La manera correcta de enviar el documento PDF directamente al navegador es usando la opción `I`:

```
$pdf->Output('I', $file);
```

Según puedes ver en la [documentación](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm):

> string Output([string dest [, string name [, boolean isUTF8]]])
>
> **dest**
>
> > Destination where to send the document. It can be one of the following:
> >
> > `I`: send the file inline to the browser. The PDF viewer is used if available.
> >
> > `D`: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by name.
> >
> > `F`: save to a local file with the name given by name (may include a path).
> >
> > `S`: return the document as a string.
> >
> > The default value is I.

En castellano, el parámetro `dest` puede ser:

- `I`: envía los datos directamente al navegador. Se usaría el visor PDF del navegador si está disponible.
- `D`: se envía directamente al navegador forzando la descarga del archivo.
- `F`: guarda el PDF en un archivo.
- `S`: devuelve el contenido del PDF en forma de cadena de caracteres.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar la opción S que te devuelve el archivo a una variable php

```
$strPdf = $pdf->Output("",'S');
```

y para mostrarlo en el navegador mira mi respuesta en este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7230/problemas-al-mostrar-un-archivo-pdf-en-el-navegador/7334#7334)

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Ya comienzo a probarlo

Comment: Recuerda votar por la respuesta que mas te ayudo

Answer (score 0):

Así es como yo lo hago (según la [documentación oficial](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm)

```
$pdf->Output('I'.$file);
```

Si traduces, viene que el navegador debe tener un visor de PDF.

Consulta esta información:

[Mozilla](https://support.mozilla.org/es/kb/visualiza-archivos-pdf-en-firefox-sin-descargarlos)
[Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm?hl=es)

Si usas otro navegador… buscan en google:

tu_navegador visor PDF.

Creo que tu problema es que el navegador no tiene visor de PDF.

Comment: Podrías editar tu respuesta y agregar por que la forma en la que lo haces funciona por favor? Así aumentarás su calidad, será mejor recibida y tanto el autor de la pregunta como otros que tengan el mismo problema podrían aprender algo nuevo. Además, Stack Overflow no es un repositorio de código.

Comment: @DanteS. perdón por olvidar las normas. Pido disculpas a la comunidad. Actualicé la respuesta y añadí otra posible solución.

Comment: Por mi parte estás perdonado c: Además, solo quería ayudarte a dar mejores respuestas y contribuir mejor nwn No se si tu respuesta son solo enlaces, pero te aviso que si pones enlaces, debes incluir en la respuesta la parte más importante de estos. Recuerda que si los links se caen, la respuesta se volverá inutil.